# QML Calendar: change first day of week

Tags: calendar, qml

Is there any way to change the first day of the week on QML Calendar?
Not only Monday/Sunday, but also for any day of the week.

I found a workaround for Monday/Sunday; force Qt.locale() for a country which has Monday or Sunday specified as first day of the week, but it is not extended to the rest of the days. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using QtQuick.Controls 2?
If so, and you are using qt.labs.calendar can use a locale object which has its property "firstDayOfWeek" to whatever you need and then, using it with your "MonthGrid" item.
Links to check:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-calendar-monthgrid.html
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-locale.html#firstDayOfWeek-prop

Comment: Thanks! I was using QtQuick.Controls 1.4 (with Qt 5.6.2), but we recently upgraded to Qt 5.9.1, I will give it a try ;)

Comment: by the way @albertTaberner, "firstDayOfWeek" cannot be written,"Holds the first day of the week according to the current locale"